# How do I make a virtual shopping cart within an app?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want the user to press a button in one activity and then have that activity send data to the shopping cart activity to add two pieces of information: the item name and the item price.

I've tried using intents in every way to add to an array located in the shopping cart activity. I can't seem to make the item name pop up on the UI in shopping cart activity.

```
//activity one xml file
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button20"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="99dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="400dp"
    android:text="5 Miles - $5"
    android:onClick="createItem"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

//activity one
package com.example.qwertyuiop;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import static com.example.qwertyuiop.Cart.itemNames;
import static com.example.qwertyuiop.Cart.totalCost;

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
}

public void createItem(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Cart.class);
    i.putExtra("1", itemNames.add("test"));
    i.putExtra("2", totalCost + 5);

    }
}

//shopping cart activity

public class Cart extends AppCompatActivity {
static ArrayList<String> itemNames = new ArrayList<String>();
static int totalCost = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.cartlv);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android . R . layout . simple_list_item_1, itemNames);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}

//shopping cart xml
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/cartlv"
    android:layout_width="395dp"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="215dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

What I want to happen is when the user presses on button 20, activity_second sends an intent to activity_cart to add to its ArrayList "itemNames" and to add 5 to its variable totalCost. Then I'd like the ArrayAdapter in activity_cart to display the contents of "itemNames" on the screen.